# Sniffer that filters IPv6 packets

Tags: python, ipv6, libpcap, scapy, sniffer

I have a simple sniffer of packets using **Python** and **pcapy**.

```
pc = pcapy.open_live(str(self.port), max_bytes, promiscuous, read_timeout)
#My problem is here
pc.setfilter('???')
pc.loop(-1, self.recv_pkts)
```

I need to drop all IPv6 packets and capture everything else (including pure L2 packets etc).
It should be possible to do so using **setfilter()** function, however I can't find any example of how to pass everything besides. I really don't want to manually parse each packet in python and check that it's not IPv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pc.setfilter('not ip6')
```

Reference: http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html